# отсортировать простой массив по возрастанию средней цифры

Tags: python, массивы

имеется задача: отсортировать массив из трехзначных чисел (100-999) по возрастанию средней цифры в числе. Например, мы вводим массив [356 589 425 658] , получаем результат [4**2**5 6**5**8 3**5**6 5**8**9] . Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением поставленной задачи.

Comment: Ваша задача - узнать, как делается сортировка с помощью  key=lambda и как выделить среднюю цифру.

Comment: извиняюсь за наглость, не могли бы вы написать код, который решает поставленную задачу? просто, я изучаю программирование в другом направлении и я не смогу быстро понять, что к чему в key=lambda

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: сделайте из каждого числа кортеж, отсортируйте по второму элементу и соберите снова в число... что, кстати, если вторые - одинаковые?

Comment: @Матвей `print(sorted([356, 589, 425, 658], key = lambda x: x // 10 % 10))` Неужели это мега сложно?